# How to use two databases in Asp.net MVC using WindsorContainer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, castle-windsor

I am using WindsorContainer and Nhibernet for database access. I use following code to initialize the container on application_start event and it works fine with single database.

```
  Container = new WindsorContainer();
 ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(Container.Resolve<IControllerFactory>());
```

Now, I want to use another database in my application. Please suggest me that how I can initialize the another container(WindsorContainer) object with different db.

Answer (score 3):

In my setup I have two databases, which I refer to as the "Transactional" database and the "Data Warehouse" database.

I have a "Session Factory" interface:

```
public interface ICmsSessionFactory
{
    ISession GetTransactionalSession();
    ISession GetDataWarehouseSession();
    void Release(ISession session);
}
```

The Windsor functionality will automatically generate a class that implements this interface.

Assuming you've got two static methods `CreateTransactionalSession` and `CreateDataWarehouseSession`, you can register your factory, and the sessions, as follows:

```
using Castle.Windsor;
using Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;

// ...

public static void Bootstrap(IWindsorContainer container)
{
    container
        .AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>()
        .Register(
                    Component.For<ISession>()
                            .UsingFactoryMethod(() => CreateTransactionalSession())
                            .Named("TransactionalSession")
                            .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest,
                    Component.For<ISession>()
                            .Named("DataWarehouseSession")
                            .UsingFactoryMethod(() => CreateDataWarehouseSession())
                            .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest,
                    Component.For<ICmsSessionFactory>()
                            .AsFactory()
                 );
```

Then you can make the `ICmsSessionFactory` a property of the Controller classes that require them.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [NHibernate Facility and its ISessionManager](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.NHibernate-Facility.ashx#Integration_level_C_4).